# How to install srfi modules in local copy of guile

Tags: scheme, guile, srfi

I have guile installed in /home/jcubic on shared hosting where I don't have root access and when I have this:

```
(use-modules (srfi srfi-1) (srfi srfi-26) (srfi srfi-43) (srfi srfi-60)
             (rnrs bytevectors) (ice-9 binary-ports) (srfi srfi-11))
```

and when I run the script I've got error:

```
 ERROR: no code for module (srfi srfi-43)
```

how can I install this library to local guile instance?

Answer (score 0):

Put it anywhere you like and add the directory to your load path, either by saying something like `(add-to-load-path mydir)`, or by setting the environment variable `GUILE_LOAD_PATH`, which is probably more convenient.